# How to get the ID of an element after it has been clicked using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

So I want to return the ID of an element that is clicked so I can save that as a string value use throughout my code. For example in a rock, paper, scissors game.

```html
 <div id ="Options">
        <div id="Rock">
            <p>Rock</p>
        </div>
         <div id="Paper">
             <p>Paper</p>
         </div>
         <div id="Scissors">
             <p>Scissors</p>
         </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I attempted to use so far but it's return value when clicked is still giving me undefined when I do console.log(playerChoice).

```js
let playerChoice = Options.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let choice = e.target.id;
  return choice
})
```

Comment: Why not just get them separately? Then you don't have an Event on something that shouldn't have one. That is what I would do. Oh, Event Listeners shouldn't return anything. You just execute DOM code in there. Events are asynchronous. Note that the `event.target` might be Options and not their children.

Comment: So is it impossible to obtain a return value using an event listener?

Comment: Yes it is. `this`, when using a regular function will refer to the Element that the Event is attached to, though. You just do things when the Event happens. You can create an abstraction called a `Promise`, but it is really just executing a function when the Event occurs, so its resolve function argument will passed to the function you pass to  `.then`.

Answer (score 3):

The `e.target`, if the user clicks on one of the words, will be a `<p>`. Check the parent element instead to get to the `div`:

```js
Options.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const choice = e.target.parentElement.id;
  console.log(choice);
})
```

```html
<div id="Options">
  <div id="Rock">
    <p>Rock</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Paper">
    <p>Paper</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Scissors">
    <p>Scissors</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could also ditch the IDs altogether and check the `textContent` of the clicked `<p>`:

```js
Options.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('p')) {
    const choice = e.target.textContent;
    console.log(choice);
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="Options">
  <div>
    <p>Rock</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Paper</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Scissors</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If he decide to change `<p>Rock</p>` to a `img`, for instance, the code will no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

Target is always the child element, in that case the `<p>`. So you better attach the click event to the child divs, that way you get the same result even if you alter the hierarchy adding elements or images:

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll("#Options div");
for (el of options) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let choice = this.id;
    console.log(choice);
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="Options">
  <div id="Rock"><p>Rock</p></div>
  <div id="Paper"><p>Paper</p></div>
  <div id="Scissors"><p>Scissors</p></div>
</div>
```